# Linux C++ Timer with Soft Real Time Support

Tags: c++, linux, timer, real-time

I'm writing scheduler for my system, that should collect data from sensors.
My scheduler have got list with planed tasks. Scheduler running in one thread and running tasks in individual threads.

Please, recommend me timer in C++, that support soft real time.
I'm writing code for vanilla Linux.

P.S. I didn't found same question on StackOverflow.
P.S.S Sorry for my bad English

Comment: There's `std::chrono` and `std::thread`. Do you have any particular constraints regarding the timer's resolution?

Comment: As I know `std::chrono` and `std::thread` doesn't support soft real time.

Comment: _"soft real time"_ Please elaborate in your question what exactly you're referring to.

Comment: My system could be overloaded. So I want this process work on overloaded system without freezing.

Comment: @Dm3Ch then give your process higher priority than the process which is overloading your system.

Comment: Under "soft real time" i means that it should work with soft real time requirement

Comment: But i want timer guaranty sleeping time with ms resolution.

Comment: @Dm3Ch _"... with soft real time requirement ..."_ What kinda buzzword speech is this please? Again, can you refer to a concise definition for this term? _"But i want timer guaranty sleeping time with ms resolution."_ Ahh, now we're getting closer.

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: Annoying that this quesion was closed, and with a bad motivation. He asked for a good timer, not a 'book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clarified about that *soft real time requirement* in your comment:

> *"But i want timer guaranty sleeping time with ms resolution."*

From standard c++ you can check the actually available resolution for e.g. the `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock` using the [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) member type. If your current system implementation doesn't meet the required resolution, you may throw an exception or such.

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/m68aZz) how to do it:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        // Uncomment any of the following checks for a particular 
        // resolution in question
        if(std::ratio_less_equal<std::nano
          ,std::chrono::system_clock::period>::value) {
        // if(std::ratio_less_equal<std::micro
        //     ,std::chrono::system_clock::period>::value) {
        // if(std::ratio_less_equal<std::milli
        //     ,std::chrono::system_clock::period>::value) {
        // if(std::ratio_less_equal<std::centi
        //     ,std::chrono::system_clock::period>::value) {
            throw std::runtime_error
                ("Clock doesn't meet the actual resolution requirements.");
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: '" << ex.what() << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "The curently available resolution is: " 
              << std::chrono::system_clock::period::num << "/" 
              << std::chrono::system_clock::period::den
              << " seconds" << std::endl;
}
```

The output (at ideone system) is:

```
Exception: 'Clock doesn't meet the actual resolution requirements.'
The curently available resolution is: 1/1000000000 seconds
```

---

For sleeping a predefined time period, you can use [`std::thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) to realize a timer.

Comment: How can I change sleeping time when I called `sleep_for()`?

Comment: @Dm3Ch _"How can I change sleeping time ..."_ You cannot, once `sleep_for()` was called. You might consider a more sophisticated timer based on e.g. a condition variable that enables you to interrupt prematurely.

Comment: What you could recomend?

Comment: @Dm3Ch That'
s completely out of scope of your original question here. Please ask another one.